# Draw square within another square

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw a square (rotated 45 degree) within another square.

I wrote a function to give the coordinates of the second square, but since the Rectangle function doesn't use 4 coordinates, I'm wondering if there's another way to use the coordinates to draw the  square.

[image]

```
l1 = {{0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {0,1}};

f6[l1_, t_Integer] :=
Table[Append[l1, l1[[1]]][[i]] + Append[l1, l1[[1]]][[i+1]], {i,1,4}]/(t*2)
```

I thought it was a good idea, the only way that I understand.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2729907).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Maybe like this?

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
t = 1/2;
n = 10;
ptslist2 = NestList[pts |-> (1 - t)*pts + t*RotateLeft[pts], pts, n];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], Polygon@#, 
    Point@#} & /@ ptslist2]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], Polygon[#]} & /@ 
  Table[f6[l1, i], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry this is not exactly what I meant. I'll try to draw it since I don't know how to do it on mathematica.

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 4;
polys = NestList[Polygon[Midpoint @@@ MeshPrimitives[#, 1]] &, 
  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], n];
cols = ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/n];
rrs = MapThread[{FaceForm[#1], EdgeForm[Black], #2} &, {cols, polys}];
Graphics[rrs, Frame -> True]
```

[image]